# Routing a selection of controller methods to the root URL of the web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm porting a legacy .NET application onto .NET Core Web API.

The legacy application exposes an API that must me ported 1:1.

I've got the following request paths working perfectly fine:

```
GET https://localhost:5001/MySuperController/user@example.com
GET https://localhost:5001/MySuperController/?username=user@example.com
POST https://localhost:5001/MySuperController/?username=user@example.com

swagger: GET https://localhost:5001/doc
```

BUT I'm having problems routing the following two paths coming to the root URL:

```
GET https://localhost:5001/?username=user@example.com
POST https://localhost:5001/?username=user@example.com
```

This is my controller and swagger registration:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
if (EnvironmentConfiguration.EnvironmentType == SystemConstants.DevEnvironment)
{
    app.UseSwagger(s =>
    {
        s.RouteTemplate = "doc/{{documentName}}/docs.json";
    });
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.RoutePrefix = "doc";
        c.SwaggerEndpoint($"../doc/v1/docs.json", "API reference");
    });
}
```

And this is the controller simplified implementation:

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MySuperController
{
    // GET https://localhost:5001/MySuperController/user@example.com
    [HttpGet("{emailaddress}")]
    public IActionResult Get(...) {...}

    // GET https://localhost:5001/MySuperController/?username=user@example.com
    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult Get(...) {...}

    // POST https://localhost:5001/MySuperController/?username=user@example.com
    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(...) {...}
}
```

To support the following two queries, I've added the `[Route("")]` prefix. But now I'm matching the `https://localhost:5001/doc` into the first controller action, with `{emailaddress}` being filled with `"doc"`.

```
GET https://localhost:5001/?username=user@example.com
POST https://localhost:5001/?username=user@example.com
```

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
[Route("")]
[ApiController]
public class MySuperController
{
    // also matches https://localhost:5001/doc now :(
    // GET https://localhost:5001/MySuperController/user@example.com
    [HttpGet("{emailaddress}")]
    public IActionResult Get(...) {...}

    // GET https://localhost:5001/?username=user@example.com
    // GET https://localhost:5001/MySuperController/?username=user@example.com
    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult Get(...) {...}

    // POST https://localhost:5001/?username=user@example.com
    // POST https://localhost:5001/MySuperController/?username=user@example.com
    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(...) {...}
}
```

What's the most idiomatic way to route these queries correctly with Web API? I would prefer not to split the controller into multiple controllers if at all possible.

Comment: If you put a `[Route("/my/path-to-something")]` onto the action methods, you can define all their URLs explicitly.

Comment: I also came into complicated routing issues when porting an app. I then used `DynamicRouteValueTransformer`. See here: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/12997
you can register it in `app.useEndpoings(endpoints => endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<MyTransforer>(...)`. within this transformer you have the httpContext with all the queryparameters, the RouteValueDictionary that asp.net would use and you can use any logic to change that routing.

Comment: @MartinCostello thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @gofal3 thanks for the idea! Luckily I managed to sort things out without the really big tools you linked :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Martin Costello's comment, I worked out the following:

```
[ApiController]
public class MySuperController
{
    [HttpGet("[controller]/{emailaddress}")]
    public IActionResult Get(...) {...}

    [HttpGet("[controller]")]
    [HttpGet("/")]
    public IActionResult Get(...) {...}

    [HttpPost("[controller]")]
    [HttpPost("/")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(...) {...}
}
```

This way, the GET and POST to `/` both get resolved with the correct action, while `/doc` and any other endpoint are not intercepted by the first method, which stays under the controller.